# Dell Mini 10 Mouse Pad Problems

Tags: 10.10, mouse, touchpad, dell-mini-10

After going from 10.04 - 10.10 (not upgraded, completely reinstalled because of upgrade issues) I found a weird problem with my mouse pad. Whenever I clicked on the left or right mouse buttons (integrated into the touch pad) when I released them, it seemed like it was detecting a double click and ended up choosing the option the mouse was hovering over.

Has anyone else experienced issues like this, and if it is possible, could I fix it?

Comment: I've found that dell's have this problem with the mouse pad (in previous versions too). Try changing the mouse sensitivity, and if it keeps up, report the issue on launchpad.

Comment: I think the proper term would be "touchpad", rather than "mouse pad" :)

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned - if you feel this is in error, then please flag explaining why and the moderators will reopen it. :)

Answer (score 0):

There could be a number of reasons for a double click, sometimes it's hardware failure and sometimes it's software. If you tend to get a double click every time then it's more likely to be software.

You can check your mouse configuration from the command line by typing in:

`xinput list`

This should give you a list of mice connected to your system, one might be your dell touchpad. If you see two entries that seem to be the same device, then that might be the issue. Of course it's hard to know without your showing the results of the above command in your original post.

Either way you should certainly report the issue if it remains by typing in the following command:

`ubuntu-bug xorg`

Explain in the bug your problems.